# How do I schedule a ipnyb notebook in Sagemaker using AWS lambda?

Tags: r, aws-lambda, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I need to schedule AWS Lambda to open/run a Jupyter Notebook I have inside Sagemaker to produce a csv file once a day.

I have already created my notebook instance (let's call it Model_v1) and the Lifecycle configuration needed inside Sagemaker. I can Start the instance, run the code (R) inside the Notebook, and the code writes the CSV file I require.

I have read many posts about how to use Sagemaker with Lambda, but I'm not formally using a "training job" or a "model" / endpoint etc etc. I literally just want Lambda to
1) Start Notebook instance
2) Run .ipnyb code which generates CSV

If there is an easier way to make Sagemaker run this script once a day with another tool (instead of lambda), more than happy to change!

Answer (score 2):

https://towardsdatascience.com/automating-aws-sagemaker-notebooks-2dec62bc2c84

This blog explains this situation.

1. Start a python environment.
2. Execute the jupyter notebook.
3. Download an AWS sample python script containing auto-stop functionality.
4. Wait 1 minute. Could be increased or lowered as per requirement.
5. Create a cron job to execute the auto-stop python script.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a notebook programmatically with [`papermill`](https://github.com/nteract/papermill). [`papermill-lambda`](https://github.com/larsrinn/papermill-lambda) shows how to bring the papermill dependency into lambda, but I never tried it though. A cleaner setup is to encapsulate model science in a docker container, like is done in this [SageMaker R tutorial](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/r_bring_your_own). Then you can have a lambda function launching a training job from the lambda-compatible SDK of your choice (for example `boto3` [create_training_job](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_training_job) call, which is installed by default in lambda).

**Note that writing the model in a sagemaker-compatible docker container enables you to benefit from the full SageMaker experience in the language of your choice - here with R, including but not limited to**:

- Training job orchestration over various type of hardware and network configuration, with multiple SDKs, including and not limited to [python](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html), [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker-runtime/invoke-endpoint.html), [js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SageMaker.html), [PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/namespace-Aws.SageMaker.html), [go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/sagemaker/), [ruby](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SageMaker.html), [java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemakerruntime/AmazonSageMakerRuntime.html#invokeEndpoint-com.amazonaws.services.sagemakerruntime.model.InvokeEndpointRequest-))
- Bayesian hyperparameter search
- Native logging of hardware usage and algorithm output, optional metric dashboard with regular expressions
- 1-click deployment to managed real-time endpoint, optionally multi-availability zone and auto-scaled
- Native metadata persistence (hyperparameters, data path, artifact, training configuration and duration, among others) and search.